# Perl parse a string and substitute multiple symbols

Tags: string, perl, substitution

I've got a string:

```
$str = "\$JVM/\$JAVA8/Contents/Home"
```

On this string, I'd like to substitute the symbols **$JVM** and **$JAVA8** with the corresponding keys from this hash:

```
%con = ('\$JVM' => '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines' ,
        '\$JAVA8' => 'jdk1.8.0_192.jdk');
```

So that I can get this:

```
$target = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

I'd like to do it without any modules. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: If your string is `"$JVM/..." then you'll get a compile time error, because you don't have a `$JVM` variable declared. The double quotes `""` make Perl _interpolate_ variables. You probable don't have this string written in your code, but rather read it as input. That's something entirely different and changes the meaning if your question. Please be specific.

Comment: I have that *str* read from %ENV, actually. And when read from it it comes as **"$JVM/$JAVA8/Contents/Home"** But that's not the problem. The problem is finding a practical way to substitute those symbols with key values from a hash table. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute to a variable. The left hand side of [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) can be a hash value.

```
my $str = '$JVM/$JAVA8/Contents/Home';
my %con = (
    '\$JVM'   => '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines',
    '\$JAVA8' => 'jdk1.8.0_192.jdk'
);

$str =~ s{
  (              # capture group for $1
     \\          # the backslash in your '\$JVM' hash key
     \$          # a literal dollar sign
     [A-Z0-9_]+  # variable name
  )
}{$con{$1}}gx;
print $str;
```

Note that in your `$str`, you want to use single quotes `''` that do not do [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation), or you'll get an error as you don't have a `$JVM` variable.

At the same time, you need to pay attention to your hash keys. If they are really `'\$JVM'` and such, that means there's a literal backslash `\` and a literal dollar `$` in them.  Therefore in the pattern we need three backslashes `\\\`. Two to get a literal one (as the backslash escapes things with special meanings in regular expressions), and one to escape the dollar.

If your keys do not have this backslash, the pattern changes.

```
my %con = (
    '$JVM'   => '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines',
    '$JAVA8' => 'jdk1.8.0_192.jdk'
);

$str =~ s{(\$[A-Z0-9_]+)}{$con{$1}}g;
```

I used the [`/x` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) in the first version, which allows comments and ignores whitespace. You don't have to do that.

Comment: Re "*you'll get an error as you don't have a $JVM variable*", No, but you'll get `$JVM/...` instead of `\$JVM/...`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried it however my code contains some symbols which have '_' , e.g. like '$JAVA_HOME' and for those symbols it returns the same. I haven't talked about those other symbols to keep the question short.

Comment: @ikegami the question was edited. It was `"$JVM/..."` initially, so my annotation was correct.

Comment: @Romario do you know anything about regular expressions? You need to change the pattern to take underscores as well. Please try to _understand_ the answer and the code in it rather than just blindly copying it. If you do that, you'll eventually copy and run bad code off the internet, and cause harm to your computer.

Comment: Of course I know about regexes. I added _ inside the brackets but the **$str** still returned either the original value or some other wrong result. Btw, among the symbols there are ones like JAVA_HOME_ , JAVA8_

Comment: @Romario Sounds like there is more to it than you are telling us. The relevant information is that you can put a variable in the substitution bit. If you are having trouble with the pattern you'll tell us more details I'm afraid.